# How to access query parameter sent via form submit

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I am unable to access the query param values, in the method. in browser i see full url like http://localhost:3000/form?ssid=user&password=acder

but when I try to access this using req.url or req.originalUrl it return only /form .

PS: I am running this server in react native using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-http-bridge so I am here giving a similar express.js example. In express js i am also not able to access the params, or even via post. any help please.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
/*
cannot use these for company reasons
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser')  
//app.use(express.json())
//app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
//var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
//var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
*/
app.get('/form', (req, res) => {
    let data = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.form-inline {  
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
align-items: center;
}

.form-inline label {
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

.form-inline input {
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.form-inline .sbt { 
padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #002060;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 50px;
}

.form-inline button:hover {
background-color: #002060;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.form-inline input {
margin: 10px 0;
}

.form-inline {
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
}
}
</style>
    <script>
    function sendData() {

       //window.location.replace('http://www.w3schools.com:1234/ssid='+ssid.value+'pass='+pass.value);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2><b>Login</b></h2>
      <form class="form-inline"  action="/form1" method="post">
      <label for="ssid">Wi-Fi Name (SSID): </label>
      <input type="text" id="ssid" name="ssid" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="password">Wi-Fi Password: </label>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value=""><br><br>
      <input class="sbt" type="submit" value="Connect">
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>`;

    //Build our response object (you can specify status, mime_type (type), data, and response headers)
    let res1 = {};
    res1.status = "OK";
    res1.type = "text/html";
    res1.data = data;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(Buffer.from(data));


})

app.post("/form1",urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + String(req.originalUrl);
    console.log("originalUrl",String(req.url))
    console.log("inside form1",req.body.ssid);
    return {"req.body.":"ok"}
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

"window.location.search" will give you answer of query as a "?ssid=user&password=acder"

Comment: i tried this i  am getting ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: try ${window.location.search} or {window.location.search}

Comment: and if its still not working and upload error image

Comment: it will not work because in Node windows do not exist. if you will see my code above i wanto to access that data in /form1 endpoint.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Javascript must support window.location method...try this